# Custom HTML on Tumblr. Hyperlinks not connecting

Tags: html, tumblr

I have a simple Tumblr page (hyperlinks only) that is entirely my custom HTML. All the hyperlinks to other Tumblr pages (other Tumblr-based sites) work fine, but any pages that want a redirect out of the Tumblr Universe won't connect (unless I command+click and choose "open in another tab" option). 
So, this hyperlink works fine:

```
<h3><a href="https://fiveminutesfilm.tumblr.com">Project-Film Short ("Five Minutes")</a></h3>
```

But, this hyperlink will only happen with that "open in another tab" workaround.

```
<h3><a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=ELasVLKHIERzk">Project-Series (EASY TO ASSEMBLE)</a></h3>
```

My question to the community is: do you know of a Tumblr-specific piece of HTML that is necessary to add in order to have hyperlinks to non-Tumblr pages connect as well as the hyperlinks to pages in the Tumblr Universe do?

Comment: please include code as editable text instead of links to images

Comment: Thanks you. Done.

Comment: What exactly happens when you do a regular click on a link? It just does nothing?

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors when you click a link? Open your console (command click and click inspect) and then click the link and see if you get any javascript errors. It sounds like javascript is intercepting the click but something is preventing it from doing what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Kodos, thanks for your comments. I just discovered something. When I go to this site through its Tumblr url, all the code hyperlinks correctly. But, when I arrive at the site via the web-forwarding url, I have this problem. So, I don't believe there's anything wrong with the HTML, but rather in the web forwarding function. Going to talk with my hosting service. Thanks for your time.